# Calling superclass getter method directly instead of property throws javax.el.MethodNotFoundException

Tags: jsp, el, wildfly

In WildFly9 we use Spring Data and we have a JSP with a working code like this (page type is PageImpl):

```
${page.first}
${page.last}
${page.isLast()}
```

But this line is not working:

```
${page.isFirst()}
```

We get javax.el.MethodNotFoundException

Is this a bug or maybe I have miss something from the EL documentation?

I narrowed the problem: we try to call a 'bridge method' on this object, and bridge methods cannot be seen by the appserver. I found this in this source: https://github.com/jboss/jboss-el-api_spec/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/el/Util.java

```
List<Wrapper> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (Method method : methods) {
  if (method.getName().equals(name) && !method.isBridge()) {
     result.add(new MethodWrapper(method));
  }
}
```

But I still dont really understand why we cannot reach this simple method.

Comment: variable name suggest that you are trying to access this method from a collection, but i assume it is just a bad name?

Comment: Yes. This has nothing to do with collections.

Comment: I think it should work with that syntax, at least in newer JEE versions. maybe more context would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WildFly9 the EL method resolution changed from the previous releases. From now on we cannot reach bridge methods cause they are filtered out by the WildFly's method resolver.

If we use public libraries in projects we can meet Bridge methods more often than we expect. The simplest case where there is a package private class with a public method and a public class extended this. In this case there will be a bridge method in the child class and we cannot reach this method in WildFly9'-s EL.

Parent.java

```
class Parent {
    public String methodToCall() {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Child.java

```
public class Child extends Parent {
}
```

JSP

```
${child.methodToCall()}
```